# How can I copy an email workflow from one SharePoint site to another in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, workflow, sharepoint-foundation

I am creating separate sub-sites on my SharePoint 2010 site for each different Line of Business in my organization. I've created a list that generates an automated email based on list responses on one sub-site, and need to copy and modify this list to each additional LOB sub-site. I have created a new list on a different sub-site using templates, but the email workflow I created is not available in the second sub-site. How can I copy the workflow I created in my first sub-site to the others?

Comment: is it SharePoint designer workflow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are couple of ways to copy it.

1. using the codeplex solution which move the workflows: [SP 2010: How to copy workflows from one site collection to another](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/sharepointwarrior/2012/03/14/sp-2010-how-to-copy-workflows-from-one-site-collection-to-another/)
2. Another way to use the SharePoint designer then use option "export to visio & import to visio option": [Copying/Moving SharePoint 2010 Designer Workflows](https://chanakyajayabalan.wordpress.com/2012/01/02/copyingmoving-sharepoint-2010-designer-workflows/) here are the steps from blog:

   - In the first(source) site, create the required workflow and publish it.
   - Now select Export to Visio option which allows you to save the workflow with a .vwi extension. (Refer this workflow hereafter as source workflow).
   - Now go to the destination site where you want the workflow to be copied, and create a new workflow with the same name as the previous one & publish it.
   - Now select Export to Visio option which allows you to save the workflow with a .vwi extension. (Refer this workflow hereafter as Destination workflow).
   - Now you will be having two .vwi files (one of source workflow’s – SourceWorkflowName.vwi  and other of the destination workflow’s – DestinationWorkflowName.vwi). Now add .zip extension to both the files. Now your files names should be SourceWorkflowName.vwi.zip & DestinationWorkflowName.vwi.zip.
   - Now open both the zip files, copy workflow.xoml.wfconfig.xml from destination workflow to source workflow. (Its destination to source and not source to destination).
   - From now on, we will not use the file DestinationWorkflowName.vwi.zip.  So ignore that file.
   - Remove the .zip extension from SourceWorkflowName.vwi.zip which gives you the   SourceWorkflowName.vwi file.
   - Now, go to the destination site, open workflows and click Import from Visio and browse to the SourceWorkflowName.vwi file.
   - That’s it and your workflow is copied. You can publish the workflow and run it.

Comment: Adding to this, I've found that when moving between sites, saving it as a solution template ("Save as Template" in SP Designer), then uploading it to the solution gallery in the new site and activating it, works a lot better than the Visio route, and you don't need a Visio license.

Comment: yup this is also a good option. let me include in the answer as well.